# Update ratings by changing dropdown ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to update the 'rating' of an item, the item (meetingcounter) is showing on the hire page.

I currently have this in my hire/show.

```
<%= form_for [@hire, @meetingcounter] do |f| %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 mt-2">
                    <label>Feedback</label>
                    <%= f.select :rating, Meetingcounter.ratings.keys, {}, onchange: "javascript:this.form.commit.click();", class: 'form-control' %>
                    <%= f.submit 'save', style: "display:none" %>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

But this is creating a new item, I only want to update the rating of the item I am changing.

In the picture below, I want to change the rating of the last item (for instance) but when I fill the form, creates a new item.

This is the whole table body code for better understanding.

```
<tbody>
    <td><%= meetingcounter.meeting_no %></td>
    <td><%= meetingcounter.time_done&.strftime("%a %I:%M%P") %>, <%= meetingcounter.date_done %></td>
    <td>      
        <%= form_for [@hire, @meetingcounter] do |f| %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 mt-2">
                    <label>Feedback</label>
                    <%= f.select :rating, Meetingcounter.ratings.keys, {}, onchange: "javascript:this.form.commit.click();", class: 'form-control' %>
                    <%= f.submit 'save', style: "display:none" %>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><%= time_ago_in_words(meetingcounter.created_at) %> ago</td>
    <% if current_user.is_admin? %>
        <td><%= link_to( 'Delete', [meetingcounter.hire, meetingcounter], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } )%></td>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: The issue here is most likely bad input. If you pass a persisted record to `form_for` it will use `method: :patch` - are you sure `@meetingcounter` isn't actually a new record or nil?

Comment: I think ```@meetingcounter``` is actually nil, ```@meetingcounter``` should actually be the current meetingcounter (i.e meetingcounter with an id), how do I resolve that please?

Comment: Usually you should have an edit method in your controller that fetches the existing record and renders the form for it. look at Rails standard action here - you're probably missing edit https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: Perhaps you should use the local variable `meetingcounter` instead of the instance variable?